# Calling/saving methods variables with java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a bank program using methods in java, it works fine for going it through the program once but when it goes back to repeat the process it seems like it doesn't save the variable previously done. For example I start off with $10 then deposit $5 it displays that I have $15 but once I go back to see "account info" it restarts the value of the variable all over again and back to its original Value of $10. How can i go back and repeat the process while taking the changed values everytime. Hope this makes sense...

```
package learning;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double balance;

    public double depos(double x) {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit?");
        x+=input.nextDouble();
        balance=x;
        return balance;
    }
    public double withdraw(double x) {
        System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw?");
        x-=input.nextDouble();
        balance = x;
        return balance;
    }
    public double info(double x) {
        balance = x;
        return balance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account acc =  new Account();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        double money;
        System.out.println("enter your initial balance!");
        money = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Welcome!");

        while (choice !=4) {
            System.out.println("1.Deposit");
            System.out.println("2.Withdraw");
            System.out.println("3.Check Account Info");
            System.out.println("4.Exit");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                double pick1 = acc.depos(money);
                System.out.println("you now have Rp " +pick1+"\n");
                break;  
            case 2:
                double pick2 = acc.withdraw(money);
                System.out.println("You now have RP "+pick2+"\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                double pick3 = acc.info(money);
                System.out.println("your current balance is Rp "+pick3+"\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("thank you!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not ask for the value in the `Account` class, but in the main only and use a constructor for the initial value

```
public class Account {
    double balance;

    public Account(double init){
        balance = init;
    }

    public double depos(double val) {
        balance += val;
        return balance;
    }

    public double withdraw(double val) {
        balance -= val;
        return balance;
    }

    public double info() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

And the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0;
    System.out.println("enter your initial balance!");
    double money = input.nextDouble();
    Account acc =  new Account(money);

    while (choice !=4) {
        System.out.println("1.Deposit\n2.Withdraw\n3.Check Account Info\n4.Exit");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("how much do you want to deposit?");
            double pick1 = acc.depos(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("you now have Rp " +pick1+"\n");
            break;  
        case 2:
            System.out.println("how much do you want to withdraw?");
            double pick2 = acc.withdraw(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("You now have RP "+pick2+"\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            double pick3 = acc.info();
            System.out.println("your current balance is Rp "+pick3+"\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("thank you!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight your changes? It is hard to spot.

Comment: `money` is not always 0, its just the same value for the whole execution of  `while(){}`, because it is read from input before the `while` block

Answer (score 0):

That is because the *balance* in ***acc*** ooject is not updated with latest value :)